# Using iRAPP Terminal server for accesing MAC Machine through Thin Clients

Tags: mac, terminal-server, thin-client

How to connect 20 Thin clients to a MAC machine/Server using iRAPP Terminal server.

Comment: You mean a Macintosh or is this a special bit of hardware called a MAC?

Answer (score 1):

Well you're not helping yourself here Gautam, you've given us very little to go off and you've clearly not looked at the manufacturer's website - like I just did - because on there it quite clear states that you can connect via the RDP protocol. So any thin client (you don't mention a make/model) that supports RDP is likely to be able to work just fine. Try googling "irapp thin" for a video of someone at iRAPP doing just this with a particular HP thin client.